# How to deal with calculated entity attribute

Tags: symfony, doctrine, entity

Let's say there is an entity called Staff.

It has a number of persistent attributes, such as:
- Name
- Experience
- Age

I want to create a "virtual" attribute, that is based on the Experience and Age, called 'Salary'. For example: $salary = ($experience + $age) * 100

But I don't want to persist the Salary attribute. The reason is that I want to let the Salary attribute get's updated automatically whenever the age or experienced values change.

I have two questions regarding this:

- Is the Entity file a good place to store the getSalary() function?
- How can I make it so that whenever a Staff entity is called, the salary variable will be filled with the salary that is calculated based on age & experience?

Comment: Why do you need a salary variable?  Seems like getSalary() can just calculate it whenever it is needed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is the Entity file a good place to store the getSalary() function?

Yes, it is.

Not every field in your entity has to be mapped to a database field.

Also, entities can contain methods other than simple getters and setters. IMO as long as those methods operate on the entity fields, they belong to the entity.

> How can I make it so that whenever a Staff entity is called, the salary variable will be filled with the salary that is calculated based on age & experience?

You could use one of the Doctrine's [lifecycle events](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/current/reference/events.html), for example the postLoad event, which is called after entity is loaded to the entity manager.

Note, that you don't have to be storing calculation results in a property. Your calculation is simple and it's probably better to define a getter.

Comment: I thought same but unfortunately DoctrineHydrator doesn't bind the associated form field for some reason. It only works if I persist the entity property - which is "total" property calculated by unit price and quantity. :(